# What mistake did I make finding $\arg (\sqrt{3}-i)$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

What mistake did I make finding $\arg (\sqrt{3}-i)$?

I figured it will be in the 4th quadrant and look like:

[image]

So $\arg{z} = - \arctan{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{1}} = -\frac{\pi}{3}$

The right answer is supposed to be $-\frac{\pi}{6}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tangent is opposite over adjacent, which is $y$ coordinate over $x$ coordinate. You have it the other way around.

Comment: Oh yes, I was thinking it was a small mistake too, didn't manage to see that ...